# How can I change the permission of an external hard drive and access it?

Tags: mount, chmod, ntfs, nixos, chown

I try to access an external hard drive with an ntfs filesystem from NixOS.

Is it correct that I have to create a mounting point? Where do you usually create a mounting point?

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/b/TDrive
sudo chmod a+rwx /media{,/b,{/TDrive}}
sudo chown -R b:users /media
```

and everything looks good:

```
$ ls -ld /media/b/TDrive
drwxrwxrwx 2 b users 4096 Oct 21 11:42 /media/b/TDrive
```

But when I mount the external hdd, the permission and ownership change.

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/b/TDrive
$ ls -ld /media/b/TDrive/
dr-x------ 1 root root 4096 Oct 18 15:02 /media/b/TDrive/
$ cd /media/b/TDrive/
bash: cd: /media/b/TDrive/: Permission denied
```

What can I do?

The above problem doesn't happen on another computer running Ubuntu.

Comment: Read `man mount`, there are NTFS options. Be sure that the Windows system(s) you connect the drive to have "Fast Boot" turned OFF, or the  drive will look funny to Linux. Beware some Windows updates turn "Fast Boot" ON.

Comment: Be careful not to write to an NTFS drive from a Unix-based OS! It may corrupt the drive. The proposed fix for this bug has not yet made it into the kernel, at least on Linux.

Comment: @waltinator The above problem doesn't happen on another computer running Ubuntu.

Comment: @MikeWaters The above problem doesn't happen on another computer running Ubuntu.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NTFS-3G Read the manual... 
Especially this "ntfsfix /dev/your_NTFS_partition"

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct that I have to create a mounting point? Where do you
> usually create a mounting point?

In most cases, **no**, you don't need to create a new directory as a mounting point. Modern GNU/Linux distros (at least desktop-oriented ones) with desktop environments will do that for you. For example, if you use Plasma or Gnome to graphically mount your external hard drive, a new folder will be created at `/run/media/<your_username>/<label_partition>/` and used as mounting point to  your disk. This directory will be deleted when you unmount the disk, too.

Whenever I manually mount anything, I usually create a subdirectory at `/mnt`. For example, `/mnt/backup` or `/mnt/iso_image`.

> What can I do?

I have never used NixOS before, but it doesn't look like a generic desktop-oriented distro based on a quick reading on their website. Things that work out of the box on Ubuntu may need some additional configuration on NixOS. In particular for your problem, [in their wiki](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/NTFS) they mention that **you should enable NTFS suppport**.

So after you do that, try to mount with

```
# mkdir /mnt/my_disk
# mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/<your_disk_partition> /mnt/my_disk
```

Read the [`ntfs-3g` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g) for more details, specially regarding permissions. The previous command will mount your ntfs partition with standard Linux permissions applied.

Also, [as pointed out by @waltinator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674273/how-can-i-change-the-permission-of-an-external-hard-drive-and-access-it#comment1272625_674273), double check that the ntfs partition is not left in an inconsistent state by Windows. `ntfs-3g` will warn you and mount the partition in read-only mode. But probably this is not the case if you were able to mount the same disk using Ubuntu.

Comment: Read `man hier` - `description of the filesystem hierarchy`.

Comment: Thanks. Are `mount -t ntfs-3g` and `mount -t ntfs` the same?

Comment: A second question. What does " enable NTFS suppport." in NixOS mean? What in other Linux distribution (e.g. Ubuntu/Debian) is  " enable NTFS suppport." in NixOS equivalent to?

Comment: Regarding first question, probably they are the same. Check [this](https://serverfault.com/a/304356/409316), but double check because it may be different on NixOS.

Comment: And regarding the second question, I don't know exactly what it means "enable NTFS support" on NixOS. I suspect that it enables the fuse driver, but you should ask the developers to be sure. In other distors (e.g. Arch Linux), to enable NTFS support you should install the driver and utilities by installing the package `ntfs-3g`.